# How to stream the video from one PC to another with an acceptable quality and synchronization?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, obs

**I have the following task**: to organize the broadcast of several gamers on the director's computer, which will switch the image to, to put it simply, the one who currently has more interesting gameplay.

The obvious solution would be to raise an RTMP server and broadcast to it. We tried that. The image quality clearly correlates with the bitrate of the broadcast, but the streams aren't synchronized and there is no way to synchronize them. As far as I know, it's just not built into the RTMP protocol.

We also tried streaming via [UDP, SRT and RTSP](https://obsproject.com/forum/resources/obs-studio-send-an-udp-stream-to-a-second-pc-using-obs.455/) protocols. We got minimal delay but a very blurry image and artifacts from lost packets. It feels like all these formats are trying to achieve constant FPS and sacrifice the quality.

**What we need**:

- A quality image.
- Broken frames can be discarded (it's okay to have not constant FPS).
- Latency isn't important.
- The streams should be synchronized within a second or two.

There is an assumption that broadcasting on UDP should be a solution, but some kind of intermediate buffer is needed to provide the necessary broadcasting conditions. But I don't know how to do that. I assume that we need an intermediate ffmpeg instance, which will read the incoming stream, buffer it and publish the result to some local port, from which the picture will be already taken by the director's OBS.

Is there any solution to achieve our goals?

Answer (score 0):

NDI is perfect for this, and in fact used a lot to broadcast games. Providing your network is in order, it offers great quality at very low latency and comes with a free utility to capture the screens and output them in NDI. There are several programmes supporting the NDI intake and the broadcasting (I developed one of them). With proper soft- and hardware you can quite easily handle a few dozen games. If you're limited to OBS then you'll have to check it supports NDI, but I'd find that very likely. Not sure which programmes support synchronisation between streams, but there's at least one ;). See also ndi.newtek.com.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, NDI isn't an option: it requires a lot of bandwidth, which is not available for all players. It does also not work with virtual networking: we were able to see each other's PCs, but no video was shown :(

Comment: I don't get this from your Q but if (some) gamers are remote then use NDI HX for their streams. NDI 5 supports the internets..

Comment: I don't see any integration of this tool into OBS or any other desktop application. There are only paid mobile apps out there. What we need is an image from a PC.

Comment: That's part of NDI so that's easy. I suggest reading up on NDI, or using one of the program's forums, or even paid support. Enjoy!